# window.open with get parameter returning 500 error when deployed to server

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, mysql

Hi folks i am doing a reporting using windows.open() for the printouts. everything works well if im using my xampp on local. but when I deployed, strange thing happened

```
<?php
$salesRecord = $_GET['sr_record'];
echo $salesRecord;
require_once '../../resources/db.config.php';

    $db = DATABASE::instance();
    $mysqli = $db->get(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />   
    <title>SOB CASH RECEIPT</title> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style2.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" />
</head>

<!--<body onload="window.print(); window.close();">-->
<body onload="window.print();">
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <textarea id="header">SOB CASH RECEIPT</textarea>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div id="customer">               
            </div>

            <table id="items" style="margin: 10px 0 0 0;">  
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">No</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;">Flight #</th>
                    <th style="width: 12%;">Date</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;">Route</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;">Total Sales</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;">IDR</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;">US$</th>
                </tr>
<?php
$cr1res = $mysqli->query("SELECT ds.flight_id, ds.flight_date, ds.flight_sector, ds.total_payment, ds.cash_sales_amount "
        . "FROM detail_sr ds WHERE ds.SR_ID = '$salesRecord'");
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cr1res)) {
?>
                <tr class="item-row">
                    <td align="center"><span class="price"><?php echo $count; ?></span></td>
                    <td align="center"><span class="price">GA <?php echo $row['flight_id']; ?></span></td>
                    <td align="center"><span class="price"><?php echo $row['flight_date']; ?></span></td>
                    <td align="center"><span class="price"><?php echo $row['flight_sector']; ?></span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span class="price"><?php echo number_format($row['total_payment']); ?></span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span class="price"><?php echo number_format($row['cash_sales_amount']); ?></span></td>
```

Data from the database is not showing up and only half page is showing up before this line

```
<?php
$totalMaster = $mysqli->query("select sum(ds.master_sales_amount) summaster from detail_sr ds where ds.SR_ID = '$salesRecord'")->fetch_object()->summaster;
$totalVisa = $mysqli->query("select sum(ds.visa_sales_amount) sumvisa from detail_sr ds where ds.SR_ID = '$salesRecord'")->fetch_object()->sumvisa;
?>
<textarea id="header">CREW MOTIVATION PROGRAM</textarea>
```

everything after this line just disappeared...
my error code as follows,

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://148.109.100.21/SOBCASHIER/html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php?sr_record=2016/04/06/SR-SOB-888-1"

Please help me with this matter...

Comment: what does the error log say? It should give you more detail about what is wrong. A 500 error is a generic "something went wrong" that could be one of a thousand things. You need to find what exactly is causing the error from the error log.

Comment: Also, sql injection warning. You should never put values from `$_GET` (or any other user input) directly into your query. Saving `$_GET['sr_record'];` to a variable and using that variable is doing nothing to help.

Comment: hi Jonathan thats the only error log i got from firebug. and the response from the server and the output are identical. My queries didnt work at all in this schema. whereas it worked perfectly on xampp local. Can you suggest me the better way to prevent injection in my scenario ?

Comment: firebug is not an error log. The error log is the php error log. Whenever php has an error, it writes to this log. What is causing the error can be as simple as not using quotes properly or trying to access a key in an array that doesn't exist. The php error log is what would tell you the issue. Firebug just shows you the response from the server. What you want is the error log on the server.

Comment: You can also try turning on error reporting and setting display errors to on within the php file. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(-1);` to the first line after `<?php`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/SOBCASHIER/html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php on line 42

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /var/www/html/SOBCASHIER/html/reports/cashreceipt_print.php on line 87

those two error i got from the reporting. I didnt find those on localhost...

Comment: The issue would be that your query is failing for some reason which means it returns false, not an instance of a result object where you could call fetch. You should check that it returned a valid result (even zero rows is a valid result) and if it failed, echo out `$mysqli->error` (https://php.net/mysqli_error) to see what the issue was. You could also echo out the query before running it and try running it in another app like phpmyadmin to see if/where the query is failing. Just a guess, but did you transfer over all the tables and data?